# ios Photo Framework: Error in saving image

Tags: ios, jpeg, photosframework

I am editing the content of an image and performed the steps mentioned in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset?language=objc). But I am getting following error. 
error   NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709551615  0x000060000065cfb0

The content of the image got changed but I cannot see the the option to revert the changes. Also the thumbnail of the image is not changed and still showing the old content. Please tell me what could be the issue. I am editing jpeg image.

Code is below. Here imageData is the modified data of the image and metaDic is the metadata. getAssetIdentifier gives the identifier of the asset i want to modify

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) imageData, NULL);
CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(source);

__block NSMutableData *dest_data = [NSMutableData data];
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)dest_data,UTI,1,NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) metaDict);

BOOL success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
CFRelease(source);
CFRelease(destination);
   if(success) {
    NSString *assetIdentifier = [self.delegate getAssetIdentifier];

    PHFetchResult* assetResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[assetIdentifier] options:nil];
    if(assetResult.count){
        __block PHAsset *asset = [assetResult firstObject];
        [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {

            __block PHContentEditingOutput  *output = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc] initWithContentEditingInput:contentEditingInput];
            // Provide new adjustments and render output to given location.
            output.adjustmentData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc] initWithFormatIdentifier:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] formatVersion:[PSSettings sharedSettings].appVersion data:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:@""]];

            __block NSURL *fileUrl = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
            [dest_data writeToURL:fileUrl atomically:YES];

             if([asset canPerformEditOperation:PHAssetEditOperationContent]){
                 [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                     // Create a change request from the asset to be modified.
                     PHAssetChangeRequest *request = [PHAssetChangeRequest changeRequestForAsset:asset];
                     request.contentEditingOutput = output;
                 } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                     if(success && completionBlock) {
                        completionBlock(error, fileUrl);
                     }
                 }];
             }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: What is the error.description ?

Comment: @Daniel In my case, for the same error code `18446744073709551615  `, error.description is `@"The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)"`

Answer (score 0):

I was using contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL for writeToURl call while I should be using output.renderedContentURL

Answer (score 0):

This call is failing, that strange error shows up when the file does not exist. Check return value of the file write call and the error. Check dest_data is not nil, and check that file actually exists after the call.

`[dest_data writeToURL:fileUrl atomically:YES];`